# How to perform Asynchrnous task in rails using delayed_jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, delayed-job, rails-activejob

Task: 
Delete an item in `Async` manner [HomeWork]

I have already configured `Active jobs` with `delayed_jobs` in my rails application but I am still confused about performing `Async` task in rails project.

Let's take an example:
I have some item to delete from the database but I want to do it in `Async` manner. I also read about `perform_later` or `perform_now` method in `delayed_job` blogs. Here is my code which is working fine:

## Controller class

```
 def destroy
   PostJob.perform_now(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { head :ok }
    format.js { render 'posts.js.erb' }
  end
 end
```

## Job class

```
class PostJob < ActiveJob::Base
 queue_as :default

 def perform(id)
  @post = Post.find(id)
  @post.destroy
 end
end
```

According to [official doc](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#queuing-jobs) of delayed_jobs I can add `handle_asynchronously` in the end of method to run in `async` manner. How can I implement in this case?

## My Question:

1. When I am looking at `destroy` method it is not deleting the element in `Async` way. However every steps written in `destroy` method is in `Synchronous`. Am I wrong?
2. If it's not then How can I implement `destroy` method to delete `post` in async manner?
3. Backgrounding task and cron job are same thing?

## Edit -1

After giving suggestion by A Fader Darkly, I changed `perform_now` to `perform_later` which is working perfectly for `Async` process but it is not deleting the entry from table (code is fine because it works when i user `perform_now`).

Also when I am running job manually by following command, Everything works fine:

```
rake jobs:work
```

Is there any way to execute `delay_job` task as soon as the `queue` get some new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your destroy method to call:

```
PostJob.perform_later(params[:id])
```

it should happen asynchronously. If not, you have some more set-up to do.

For your questions:

1. Yes you are right, but what you say is a tautology. Everything in that method is synchronous - the job queue isn't used because of the `perform_now`. Thus destroy isn't deleting in an async way.
2. See above.
3. Cron jobs work on the operating system level and are scheduled regularly for particular times. You could have a cron job working every minute, for example, or every day, or week (on a particular day at a particular time). They run from a schedule file called a crontab.

'Backgrounding' a task simply stops it from taking over the IO of your terminal session. So you can carry on using the terminal while the process runs in the background. Generally this is done on an ad-hoc basis, so you don't have to wait for a heavy operation to complete before going on to do different tasks.

EDIT

Based on edits to the question, it sounds like Delayed Job daemon needs to be started. From the instructions:

Note: For Rails 4 replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job
When running a queue locally, omit the 'RAILS_ENV=production' part of commands.

Running Jobs
script/delayed_job can be used to manage a background process which will start working off jobs.

To do so, add gem "daemons" to your Gemfile and make sure you've run rails generate delayed_job.

You can then do the following:

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

## Runs two workers in separate processes.

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

## Set the --queue or --queues option to work from a particular queue.

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start

## Use the --pool option to specify a worker pool. You can use this option multiple times to start different numbers of workers for different queues.

## The following command will start 1 worker for the tracking queue,

## 2 workers for the mailers and tasks queues, and 2 workers for any jobs:

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pool=tracking --pool=mailers,tasks:2 --pool=*:2 start

## Runs all available jobs and then exits

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start --exit-on-complete

## or to run in the foreground

RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run --exit-on-complete

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation! 
I removed the rest of the code from `destroy` method and it is working fine. But as you mentioned that this process is `sync` not `Async`. I can make it `async` but when it is going to execute if I use `perform_later`? 

Do i need to make any changes into `delay_job_config` file?

Comment: If you use 'perform_later' then it will execute as soon as a queue is ready to process a job. Unless you have 1000s of small tasks or a few really heavy ones, perform_later will be close to immediate.

You won't know the result of the operation in the code that calls it, though.

There's no need to remove the 'respond_to' block, if that's what you mean about removing code.

Comment: ok, Got it But when I am running method with `perform_later` and refresh the page it's not deleted yet even after 5 minutes. When I check the job log. It made a new entry but the job is not run yet. Actually my homework is to start the deleting process when I clicked on `Delete`  from UI

Comment: @A Fader Please have a look at the Edit section of question

Comment: Sounds like the queue isn't running. If you're using the 'delayed job' gem you need to have a queue process running. Think of it like a webserver - a webserver needs to be running to serve pages, the queue needs to be running to process jobs. Look here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job and find the section on 'Running Jobs'

Comment: If you don't want the hassle, the 'suckerpunch' gem also plugs into Rails just as easily, but processes jobs in the same process as the webserver.